# How to force crontab to check for changed files

Tags: cron, gentoo

I have a gentoo Linux system in which I am logged in as root. How can I force `crontab` to read new/changed files in `/etc/cron.d` immedeately, so that even a new cronjob is executed if even only seconds away?

Answer (score 1):

`cron` has a granularity of one minute, starting at the 0 second. The files are checked, and reloaded if necessary, before executing the next statement.

(If in doubt, you can of course always restart cron after making the changes.)

Comment: Some historical cron implementations have an extra delay of 1 minute (jobs detected at H:M are only runnable starting at H:(M+1)). I think that all cron implementations on Linux today pick up jobs immediately, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Gilles I am 100% sure Vixie Cron picks up any change done before the minute change, I have watched the seconds counter after making a change often enough while testing out cron jobs. But also remember it being longer, that is probably where the recommendation to restart cron came from. I don't remember though where I changed no longer always doing that, with Irix or with Linux.